# Getting user's facebook ID before he's given any privileges?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get a user's facebook id before he's given any privileges or logged into an app? Or does he have to have logged in before even his facebook id could be accessed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple: no, there's no (legit) way!